# Problems When Push Notification Sending to Another Device With react-native-firebase

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I'm having a hard time sending a notification to another user using the react-native-firebase package

Environment Details:

- react-native 0.58.4
- react-native-firebase 5.2.2
- Android 8

> I am not using firebase authentication - Authentication is done by an API.

All the settings described by the [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/android) documentation (Android Notifications) have been strictly followed.

Flow:

The user is successfully authenticated. Then your channel is defined.

```
fbase.messaging().hasPermission()
   .then(enabled => {
      if (!enabled) {
         fbase.messaging().requestPermission();
      }
   });

const channel = new fbase.notifications.Android.Channel(userId, 'User Notifications', fbase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max)
   .setDescription('Logged in users notifications');
//userId is 43
fbase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);
```

Then a notification is sent to himself as follows.

```
const notification = new fbase.notifications.Notification()
  .setNotificationId('6878')
  .setTitle(`Proposta respondida por Zé Carlos`)
  .setBody('Sim, estamos à disposição. Chame-nos no chat qualquer coisa.')
  .setData({
    action: 'Proposta Respondida',
    serviceOrderId: '68',
    companyAvatar: null,
    companyName: 'Auto Mecânica Joãozinho'
  });
  notification.android.setChannelId('43');
  notification.android.setSmallIcon("ic_notification");
  notification.android.setVibrate([1000, 1000]);
  notification.android.setLargeIcon('imageUrl');
  notification.android.setTicker('Não falou nada não falou em');
```

This works, as shown in the following image.

[Notification Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcdp4.png)

The problem happens when I authenticate with another user (on another device) and try to send that same notification. It does not arrive on the first device.

It would be required to authenticate through the firebase fcm?

Or other settings for display the notification to another device?

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The way you choosed, you only able to send local notifications.

For example this is used, if you receive an *data-only messages from FCM*, which is not displayed by your app automatically... you have to handle this. (Described [here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/messaging/receiving-messages#3)-Listen-for-FCM-messages))

To send Notification to other devices, you have to use `firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage()`

Have a look here: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/messaging/upstream-messages

Hope, thats helps you a bit.

Comment: Or you can call firebase push notification api

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref